# Android Device Encryption - When does it come in to play?

Tags: android, encryption

My device has no External SD Card. When I perform the "Encrypt Device" on my device, I understand that this encrypts data in the internal SD card. Every time I switch on my device, I am asked for the password to decrypt the data.

My question is -

How do I test if the data is actually encrypted or not? When I connect my device (with data encrypted) to a PC and try to open an image file, I can do it. Does this mean that the data is decrypted when the device is ON? Is the data encrypted only when the device is OFF? When the device is locked, I am unable to view the files irrespective of whether the device is encrypted or not.

When exactly does this device encryption help?

Answer (score 0):

Reset the phone, do not enter a password and try to get to the data.

Comment: Do you mean factory reset? Would it not delete all the data?

Comment: No factory reset. Only Normal reset = off/on

Comment: Oh Okay. How do we get the data in that case? Because the data is not accessible if the device is connected to the PC. Is there a way to access the data on the device when it is switched off (or) locked (or) when it is asking for the password during boot up?

Comment: Enable USB debugging. Settings > Applications > Development and enable USB debugging